# Crystal Reports 11.5 on Windows Server 2012 Broken

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, windows-server-2012

I'm not very Crystal Reports savvy. I have a web site running on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition.  Part of the web site project contains a Crystal Reports viewer which uses redistributable components contained in CrystalReports11_5_NET_2005.msi. It uses the `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load` method, which, when the site is moved to Microsoft Windows Server 2012, fails. 
The Load command fails with an error message that basically says I'm not even connected to the internet (which in fact I'm sure the server is connected). Everything works up until the Load command. The Windows Server 2012 IIS Application Pool is .Net4 Integrated with Support for 32 Bit Applications set to True.

In the Event Viewer I get the following Events:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: BEX Response: Not available Cab Id:
>   0
>
> Problem signature: P1: w3wp.exe P2: 8.0.9200.16384 P3: 5010885f P4:
>   StackHash_e2e9 P5: 0.0.0.0 P6: 00000000 P7:
>   PCH_01_FROM_ntdll+0x0002E11C P8: c0000005 P9: 00000008 P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_5230936ffd2c9586a6d94608bf06e66e8776b8d_1f3824c1
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   8d344128-47f2-11e4-941b-0050568d21df Report Status: 4 Hashed bucket:
>
> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time
>   stamp: 0x5010885f Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x0f3e2020 Faulting process id: 0x62c Faulting application start time:
>   0x01cfdbff4e1b8452 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path: unknown
>   Report Id: 8d344128-47f2-11e4-941b-0050568d21df Faulting package full
>   name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:

And the application Pool stops.

I really hope someone else has had this same issue.

Now that Crystal Reports has been bought and sold a couple times it appears to be very difficult to get any help with these types of issues.

Here are the assemblies listed in the web.config:

```
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you uninstall Crystal 11.5 on your development machine, and use a newer version.

Specifically, if you use the latest service pack of the Crystal Reports for VS (2010-2013), you should not have any problems. This is the free version of Crystal for VS.

See the following page for all the versions for vs2010-2015.3:
[Crystal Reports For VS](https://blogs.sap.com/2010/12/07/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio-updates-runtime-downloads/)

Comment: I ended up purchasing Crystal Reports 2013, changed the web.config to reflect the change and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely you would be using CrystalReports11_5_NET_2005.msi in an ASP.Net applicaton.

The older ASP.Net version of Crystal that is normally redistributed is CRRedist2008_x86 and its CRRedist2008_x64 counterpart. And these are both Crystal 10.5.

The version you quote in your question is not the redistributable for .Net applications. Look at your web.config file, and the dlls referenced in your development project and paste them here. You'll find they are 10.5 (if older - search for crystal report redistributable for visual studio 2008) or 13.0.2 (newest)

see [Crystal Reports 13 And Asp.Net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193887/crystal-reports-13-and-asp-net-3-5) and [Deploying Crystal for VS2010](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Deploying+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Runtime)

**EDIT**

The files aren't publicised any more, but you can get to one of them from http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/downloads/redistributables/vs_2008/redist/x86/CRRedist2008_x86.msi

**EDIT 2**

For reference here are the 10.5 references

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
```

Comment: Added web config info.  After installing CRRedist2008_x86.msi still no change.

Comment: Now getting An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

Comment: Which one did you go for, x64 or x86? what does your application expect. Can you look at the web.config file and paste in what version is expected.

Comment: This new message is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286630/an-error-has-occured-while-attempting-to-load-the-crystal-reports-runtime and http://scn.sap.com/thread/3311489

Comment: 11.5.3700.0 is what the web config has.

Comment: what does this key say: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Business Objects is there a 10.5 and 11.5 below?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62532/discussion-between-reckface-and-trevorbrooks).

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed all the related crystal report patch and service pack that are compatible with your enviroment it would be enough to switch the application pool from integrated to classic.

crystal report is a really buggy software and they release a tons of patch/servicepack sadly you have to dig in sap site to find patchs.

Anyway  you are targeting an old version that is not supposed to run on ws2012 and it is not even supported anymore from SAP

You should install CrystalReport 13_0_9

Comment: what related crystal report patch and service pack?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks crystal report is a really buggy software and they release a tons of patch/servicepack sadly you have to dig in sap site to find patchs. Anyway I think that you are targetting an old and not supported anymore version

Comment: @TrevorBrooks, you may have installed the wrong version of the runtime. It's misleading, but the series of runtimes you install for a win 32 application is very different from the one you would install for a .Net application.